# Muffler pipe name? + How to replace/fix?

Tags: exhaust, muffler

A typical muffler has at least 2 pipes coming in/out of it: 1 that carries exhaust into the muffler and 1 that carries exhaust out (i.e., the "tail pipe").

**Does the pipe leading *into* the muffler have a formal name?**

[image]

I think some might refer to the pipe leading into the muffler as a "back pipe" or perhaps an "intermediate pipe" -- though I think the intermediate pipe is the pipe before the pipe in question.  I can't seem to confirm any of that. My question is concerning the pipe that directly attaches the rest of the rear exhaust system to the muffler. (usually clamped [sometimes welded??]).

---

PART B: **if this pipe is rusted at the [front] end, does the whole pipe need to be replaced?**

- If so, can it be detached easily from the muffler itself, or does it necessitate a new muffler, too?

Note: in my case (2015 Subaru legacy), the joint between rear exhaust and this pipe rusted and failed causing this muffler pipe to become completely disconnected from the rest of the exhaust before it. The rust is more or less limited to the joint itself (+ perhaps another inch). Just trying to repair (or get it repaired) the most appropriate way.

Comment: Or is it that this pipe is called the back pipe and it connects to the intermediate pipe??

Comment: I don't think there is a specific name for that; it's all general exhaust piping. The *tailpipe* is called that just to identify it as the final downstream component. You might hear someone say "mid-pipe", but this can mean anything because there are "mid-pipes" between all components (header to cat converter, cat converter to cat converter, cat converter to muffler, muffler to resonator...). Just call it what it is, the exhaust pipe between component *X* and component *Y*.